# Compress a directory in google cloud storage bucket and then download in local directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a directory named `bar` in google cloud storage bucket `foo`. There are around 1 million small files (each around 1-2 kb) in directory `bar`.

According to [this reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) if I have a large number files I should use `gsutil -m` option to download the files, like this:

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://foo/bar/ /home/username/local_dir
```

But given the number of total files (around 10^6), the whole process of downloading the files is still slow.

Is there a way so that I can compress the whole directory in cloud storage and then download the compressed directory to the local folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to compress the directory in the cloud before copying, but you could speed up the copy by distributing the processing across multiple machines. For example, have scripts so

machine1 does `gsutil -m cp -r gs://<bucket>/a* local_dir`

machine2 does `gsutil -m cp -r gs://<bucket>/b* local_dir`
etc.

Depending on how your files are named you may need to adjust the above, but hopefully you get the idea.